# Binding database to ComboBox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0

I have a `ComboBox` that connected to sql-server and I retrieve the columns on it. Here's my table

```
course_code           course

CTECH                computer technician
COMSCI               computer science
```

For example, if I select computer technician from combo box how do I retrieve the `course_code` `CTECH` in label, then if I select computer science in combo box how I retrieve the `course_code` `COMSCI` in label?

Comment: Several questions - (1) WinForms or WPF? (2) Do you have a language preference?

Comment: WINFORM VISUAL BASIC only

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole bunch of `Selected...` properties like `SelectedItem`, `SelectedValue` etc. See the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txkcsbyf.aspx) and pick the one you want/need.

What you'll probably want to do is get the [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx); if that doesn't work you'll need to be more specific on how you got the data into the combobox (databinding?).

Comment: Ok, you could post (or edit-in) the relevant code on *how* you databound the items to the combobox but did you try to use the SelectedValue as I said?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Value by using the property [Combo box].Selected Value;

also bind these properties when you bind your combo box:
comboBox1.ValueMember = "course_code";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "course";

Comment: After loading the data into DataTable or DataSet you must assign these values to both of the properties.
 comboBox1.ValueMember = "customerid";
 comboBox1.DisplayMember = "contactname";
 comboBox1.DataSource = dt;